# Understanding decoders and comparators

Tags: comparator, decoder

How can I implement the comparator of two 2-bit numbers using decoders DEC 2/4 and required logic gates? That comparator will be used to compare two 4-bit numbers. The comparator only has one output to show if the first number is bigger than the second. I created the truth table for the comparator:

[image]

A1 - higher positioned bit of the first number
A0 - lower positioned bit of the first number (mistake in the table)
B1 - higher positioned bit of the second number
B0 - lower positioned bit of the second number
X - is 1 if A>B  <=> (A1>B1) + (A1=B1)(A0>B0)

And here's my solution using decoders 2/4 and required logic gates:

[image]

Even though I did the task, I'm not completely sure if it's correct.
What I don't understand is: How do these decoders function? It's like X will always be 1 if the conditions are made, the output of the comparator will never be 0. Please correct me if I'm mistaken or correct the solution.

Edit, new solution using the true logic of decoders (not demultiplexers), please check if it is good:

[image]

Comment: What is the bottom input for the decoders you are using? Looks like they are DeMuxes, not decoders.

Comment: It's the CS (chip select) signal.

Comment: And what is the output of a non-selected chip? Tri-state? So what will be the output of a gate which has a tri-state inputs? In your drawing, for A="00" none of the rightmost decoders will be selected, so what will be the output?

Comment: The output of a non-selected should be 0, right? And if any of the gates outputs 1, then A>B and X=1.

Comment: Yep, that's what bothers me, should I just put zero next to it, or somehow connect it to X?

Comment: No, the "chip select" signal is "disabling" the outputs, putting them in the "high impedance" state. The behaviour you are describing is for demultiplexer

Comment: Oh, now I get it, so, what should I do with the "empty" outputs if A is not larger than B?

Comment: For generic method read this document: http://www.fatih.edu.tr/~aliadam/EEE122A/EEE122CombinationalLogicChapter4.pdf  Of course you might do some optimizations

Comment: Try using only 2 decoders and some logic gates.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm still not sure if I get it. So, if a decoder is selected (CS is enabled), then all outputs of the decoder are active and some of them give 0 and some 1. In case of a demultiplexer, only one output is active based on the input and if the input of a demultiplexer is 1, then it functions as a decoder and the selected output depends on the selection inputs of the demultiplexer.

Comment: Exactly. So for the sake of simplicity (and good practice with pure boolean logic), forget about CS and assume you have only `0`s and `1`s, and all of the components are always enabled.

Comment: @EugeneSh. But, how can I use the second line decoders then? How can I connect them to the first decoder? I understand my solution uses the logic of demultiplexers, but how can I do it differently? Maybe I should just use two decoders, one for A number and one for B, and just combine the outputs of both so I get what I need. Right?

Comment: Have you looked at the doc I recommended above? It is pretty comprehensive..

Comment: Yes, I have, but... i still don't get it. Do you have some time so we can finish our conversation? I don't want to be pushy :)

Comment: OK, I'll try to do another solution and edit my post with the new solution. Could you please review it then?

Comment: @EugeneSh. OK, I edited the solution, could you please check it?

Comment: @A6Tech I am writing an answer for you at this moment. Please stand by

Comment: Please, can someone explain how he got these decoders? I don't understand what to look at when connecting and choosing the inputs and outputs. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's see how to implement a function using single decoder. It is a straight-forward task having the truth table. Decoder will output `1` on the lines selected by the input, so if we just "or" the outputs corresponding to the truth table lines with X=1, we will get the exact required function:
[image]

Unfortunately there is no straightforward way to convert it to 2->4 decoders. But maybe we can divide the original function to smaller ones, suitable for 2->4 representation? Let's look at it. After some manipulations I've omitted here, the function can be represented as $$A_1B_1'+A_0B_0'(B_1'+A_1)$$
So we can see here three different 2-variable functions combined with ANDs and ORs: 
1) \$A_1B_1'\$
2) \$A_0B_0'\$ 
3) \$B_1'+A_1\$ 
while (1) and (3) are functions of the same variables and can share decoder.

So the solution would be: Implement functions (1)-(3) using the method above, and interconnect the outputs using the gates:
[image]

Comment: What is the second output of the B1A1 decoder? B1=1 and A1=0?

Comment: Look at the little numbers near the splitters. '1' stands for the MSB. The second input is for `A1B1 = "01"`, as you said.

Comment: OH OK, if we had multiple inputs, only MSB would be 1 and the rest 0?

Comment: No, I guess you are looking at the wrong numbers. Look at the top schematic, it has a splitter with bits numbered 3-0 where 3 is MSB

Comment: OH, ok, hahah, sorry for the inconvenience, i'm at the beginning of my studies. Big thanks for everything!

Comment: What if \$A_0B_0 \ne 10\$? for example, A=10 and B=00?

Comment: @nidhin (2) will be '0'

Comment: @EugeneSh. K. Now I got it. So if I am correct, you actually don't need a 3-input OR gate. There is no need of connecting (1) to OR gate.

Comment: @nidhin Why? (3) is a \$\Sigma(0,2,3)\$. Maybe it can be optimized away (i am lazy to check), but not according to steps described.

Comment: If \$A_1B_1 = 10\$ then output is 1. What ever be the value of (3). So why do we need to include that term in (3)?

Comment: @nidhin Just checked the equivalence. You are right, it will be the same function. As I said, it can be optimized, the drawing is reflecting the steps described in the text.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that I understood it correctly. +1 for the nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

Inputs of first decoder be A0 and A1. Outputs \$N_0, N_1, N_2\$ and \$N_3\$  (\$N_0\$ will be high for A='00')
Inputs of second decoder be B0 and B1. Outputs \$M_0, M_1, M_2\$ and \$M_3\$

Let the final output be Y. Then,

If A = '00' then, \$Y = `0`\$
if A = '01' then, \$Y = M_0 \$
if A = '10' then, \$Y = M_0 + M_1\$
If A = '11' then, \$Y = \overline{M}_3\$

Or,

$$Y = N_1M_0 + N_2(M_0+M_1) + N_3\overline{M}_3$$

Hardware requirement is 2 decoders + 6 gates

Comment: My logic is, no inverters XD Why didn't I come up with them? I don't know, thank you very much!